# Can I update, insert and delete records from multiple mysql servers in cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

Can I update, insert and delete from the multiple mysql nodes in the mysql cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real mysql cluster, you can delete from all. If you have replication with master and slave you have to do it on mysql master.

Comment: What about insert and update? Can I insert/update records from multiple mysql node in the cluster Where those changes should sync to other mysql nodes incluster

Comment: you can do. the master is syncing internally. Be aware to use the "mysql cluster" solution and not a simple master - slave replication. If you there update on the nodes, this will never be synced with master. For this you need the "mysql cluster" solution.